# DC Voltage Across Load in Central Tapped Full wave rectifier

Tags: rectifier

A 230 V, 60 Hz voltage is applied to the primary of a 5:1 step-down,
center-tap transformer use in a full wave rectifier having a load of 900 Ω.
If the diode resistance and secondary coil resistance together has a
resistance of 100 Ω, determine (a) DC voltage across the load, (b) DC
current flowing through the load,
can we consider the circuit as the following,

[image]

if it is the circuit then what will be the value of dc voltage across load ?,i have
considered there is not potential drop across diode ,and the dc voltage across load (900ohm) is 900/(900+50)*2 Vmax/pi is that the correct way of solving it

Comment: homework question? have you attempted it?

Comment: not a homework question it was in the slide given by my professor i have tried it

Answer (score 0):

The DC voltage and current across the load will be the RMS value of rectified sine wave. So you'd need to look up the RMS formula/multiplier for rectified sine wave. Note that the RMS voltage on both sides of the transformer is RMS for a sine wave. The RMS current, as well as RMS voltage past the diodes, is RMS for a rectified sine.